# firebase: don't get data from realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't get data from realtime database, but load is perfect.
how fix it?

```
const dbRef = database.ref();
    var data;
    dbRef.child("playlists").child(1).get().then((snapshot) => {

        data = snapshot.val();

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

data is underfined
[image]

Comment: This works for me: https://jsbin.com/fesanuy/2/edit?js,console. So we might need to see more of the problem to determine why/what isn't working for you.

Comment: @Vlad Any updates on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong in the code but could you try running it this way?

```
firebase.database().ref("playlists/1").once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
})
```

Just in case you've share a small part of your code, then there is a typo in the word 'description'. You might want to check if that's the same in your code else it'll log undefined.

Let me know if issue still persists.